# Call roles function from model in html view or controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I already have a Custom Auth that works fine. But I can only use it in my routes blocking or releasing the access. But now I would like to hide or show buttons and links for some Roles and Users, something like:

```
@if(user==admin) // this line (Auth::user->roles()) ??
<a href="admin">Configuration</a
@endif
```

But sadly I cant do that no matter how I try it. Like I said I already have this User Model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function hasAnyRole($roles)
{
    if (is_array($roles)) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I do not know how to call this functions to my blade view since Im a starter in laravel. So any help would be great, thank you. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) 
<a href="admin">Configuration</a
@endif
```

Comment: OMG it works!!! I was trying Auth::user() without the \ !!! I can not believe it kk! Really thank you my friend!!!

Comment: Hey, it gives an error when I am not logged - Call to a member function hasRole() on null - any ideas?

Comment: [SOLVED]@if((Auth::check()) && (\Auth::user()->hasRole('Guest'))) ...html here...                  @endif! Thank you again man!!!